# Cloning a Windows Store app - What should be changed?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-store

I need to create a copy of a Windows Store app that will coexist with the original one on the store. I plan to create a copy of the solution folder and then change the package display name in appxmanifest (Packaging).

Is there anything else I need to change to prevent conflicts between the apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the package display name won't be sufficient and even it's not needed - you can have two apps with the same name on your phone. The most important is **Name** (in *Identity* node) and **PhoneProductId** (in *PoneIdentity* node) - they must be different for each app. You won't edit them easily by opening *packageappx.manifest* file by double click, instead right click on the file, choose <kbd>View code</kbd> and edit mentioned data:

```
<Identity Name="SmthFromStoreWithLittleChange" Publisher="CN=something" Version="1.0.0.0" />
<mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="082abc73-hereAlsoLittleChange-ea7ea4735fbd" PhonePublisherId="any GUID here" />
```

Remember that each of this apps has its own *LocalData* folder (*LocalSettins* and other data also).

Comment: Thanks. Though in my app they aren't the same (Name and PhoneProductId). My app is a UWP app. Perhaps yours is different.

Comment: @ispiro Right, they don't need to be the same, but both should be different for each app, so you will have to change both. I've also checked this for *UWP*, though tried on temporary app where they were the same, whereas on normal app as you mentioned they are different.