# Error: DEP0001, HRESULT: 0x80073CF9 when deploying UWP app to Phone

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Despite the alike existing threads here on SO, my problem is somehow different,

I have an application that I made, I deploy it, works fine.
I copy the same application solution, make some changes on it to create an other application that have almost the same logic as the first one (can't re-code everything from scratch), deploy it, and I receive this :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Error : DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: Install failed. Please
>   contact your software vendor. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80073CF9)   MyApplication

I believe this is cause by the fact that the system is identifying it as an application that was already deployed, I tried to delete any prints left by the first solution, deleted the content of the bin and the obj folders, but didn't help.

Please what's the solution for this problem

Comment: Have you uninstalled the first app from the device? You want two solutions of the same app? If so, have you changed their ID's?

Comment: @Romasz : They are two different apps, I don't want to uninstall the first one, what is the ID, where I can find it ?

Comment: If so, then you probably need to [follow this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35118274/2681948).

Comment: @Romasz In my case, only this line is identical 
`<mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="0d4ed7b9-8b59-4303-85e7-891407b2825d" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />`
I understand that I have to change the PhoneProductId, how can I change it, should I change it as I desire or should I follow something specific ??

Comment: Then just change in one of the apps the *PhoneProductId*, for example to `PhoneProductId="0d4ed7b9-8b59-4303-85e7-891407b2823a"`.

Comment: Thx Mr @Romasz that definitely works and makes sense, I'll be deleting this question cause it seems to be duplicate, and go upvote on the other one, thx again

Comment: Not sure if deleting is apropriate - this may be useful in case somebody looks for the same error.

Comment: Then please add it as an answer, I'll happily accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Windows 10 you cannot have two apps with the same *Name* and/or *PhoneProductId*. In case you need to duplicate the app you will need to edit the *packageappx.manifest* file of one of them. You need to edit the code - right click on the manifest file, choose <kbd>View code</kbd> and edit mentioned data:

```xml
<Identity Name="LittleChangeinName" Publisher="CN=something" Version="1.0.0.0" />
<mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="082abc73-hereAlsoLittleChange-ea7ea4735fbd" PhonePublisherId="any GUID here" />
```

Remember that each of this apps has its own *LocalData* folder (*LocalSettins* and other data also).