# Can't install appx generated with Cordova through Visual Studio

Tags: cordova, powershell, windows-10-universal

I've created a Cordova application in Visual Studio and now I want to test it on my Windows Tablet.

I've generated the files I needed to install the app

[image]

I've copied the files to my tablet and run the powershell script, but then it stops with this message:

```
Installing app...
Found dependency package(s):
D:\Dev\A\Mobile\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Windows10_2.2.0.0_x86_debug_Test\Dependencies\x86\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.Debug.14.00.appx
D:\Dev\A\Mobile\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Windows10_2.2.0.0_x86_debug_Test\Dependencies\x64\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.Debug.14.00.appx
Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF9, De installatie is mislukt. Neem contact op met de softwareleverancier. (Uitzondering van HRESULT: 0x80073CF9)

NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 3835c98a-d14d-0000-2222-36384dd1d101 in the Event Log or use the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID 3835c98a-d14d-0000-2222-6384dd1d101

At D:\Dev\A\Mobile\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Windows10_2.2.0.0_x86_debug_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1:388 char:13
+             Add-AppxPackage -Path $DeveloperPackagePath.FullName -Dep ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (D:\Dev\A\Mobile..._x86_debug.appx:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

This is what I have in my powershell around line 388

```
377    $AddPackageSucceeded = $False
378    try
379    {
380        if ($DependencyPackages.FullName.Count -gt 0)
381        {
382            Write-Host $UiStrings.DependenciesFound
383            $DependencyPackages.FullName
384            Add-AppxPackage -Path $DeveloperPackagePath.FullName -DependencyPath $DependencyPackages.FullName -ForceApplicationShutdown
385        }
386        else
387        {
388            Add-AppxPackage -Path $DeveloperPackagePath.FullName -ForceApplicationShutdown
389        }
390        $AddPackageSucceeded = $?
391    }
392    catch
393    {
394        $Error[0] # Dump details about the last error
395    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: DEP0001, HRESULT: 0x80073CF9 when deploying UWP app to Phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106365/error-dep0001-hresult-0x80073cf9-when-deploying-uwp-app-to-phone)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself by removing the application first. Seems like the application can't have a duplicate name on the machine. 
There is a way to solve this, which is explained here:

[Error: DEP0001, HRESULT: 0x80073CF9 when deploying UWP app to Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106365/error-dep0001-hresult-0x80073cf9-when-deploying-uwp-app-to-phone)